# Ranking teams equal on points in a pool based on who won the game they played

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

I'm writing an application that calculates the ranking of teams in the pool stages of a rugby competition *(Rugby World Cup 2015, but it could apply to many other pool-based competitions)*.

At the completion of the pool phase, points are calculated based on wins/draws/losses/bonus points, and teams are ranked by points.  **If two or more teams are level on points, then the winner of the match in which two tied teams have played each other shall be the higher ranked.**  Once this initial ranking is complete, other criteria (points difference, tries difference, points scored, tries scored) are applied to complete the ranking process.

**I have written a query that does ALL of the above, EXCEPT the first ranking criteria - two teams level on points should be ordered based on the winner of the match in which the two teams played.**

Here is my database schema:

```
[TEAM]        [MATCH]
-TeamId       -MatchId
-TeamName     -HomeTeamId
-Pool         -AwayTeamId
              -HomeTeamScore
              -HomeTeamTries
              -AwayTeamScore
              -AwayTeamTries
```

Here is the SQL Server query I use to calculate the ranking/standings for a given pool:

```
WITH PoolResults ([MatchId], [TeamId], [Team], [P], [W], [D], [L], [PF], [PA], [PD], [TF], [TA], [TD], [PTS], [BP]) 
AS (SELECT 
        M.[MatchId], 
        M.[HomeTeamId] AS [TeamId], 
        HT.[TeamName], 
        1 AS [P], 
        CASE WHEN M.[HomeTeamScore] > M.[AwayTeamScore] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [W], 
        CASE WHEN M.[HomeTeamScore] = M.[AwayTeamScore] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [D], 
        CASE WHEN M.[HomeTeamScore] < M.[AwayTeamScore] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [L], 
        M.[HomeTeamScore] AS [PF], 
        M.[AwayTeamScore] AS [PA], 
        (M.[HomeTeamScore] - M.[AwayTeamScore]) AS [PD], 
        M.[HomeTeamTries] AS [TF], 
        M.[AwayTeamTries] AS [TA], 
        (M.[HomeTeamTries] - M.[AwayTeamTries]) AS [TD], 
        CASE 
            WHEN M.[HomeTeamScore] > M.[AwayTeamScore] THEN 4 
            WHEN M.[HomeTeamScore] = M.[AwayTeamScore] THEN 2 
            WHEN M.[HomeTeamScore] < M.[AwayTeamScore] THEN 0 
        END AS [PTS], 
        CASE 
            WHEN ((M.[AwayTeamScore] - M.[HomeTeamScore]) BETWEEN 1 AND 7) AND M.[HomeTeamTries] >= 4 THEN 2 
            WHEN ((M.[AwayTeamScore] - M.[HomeTeamScore]) BETWEEN 1 AND 7) THEN 1 
            WHEN M.[HomeTeamTries] >= 4 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS [BP] 
    FROM 
        Match AS M 
        INNER JOIN Team AS HT 
            ON M.[HomeTeamId] = HT.[TeamId] 
    WHERE 
        M.[HomeTeamScore] IS NOT NULL 
        AND HT.[Pool] = @Pool

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        M.[MatchId], 
        M.[AwayTeamId] AS [TeamId], 
        AT.[TeamName], 
        1 AS [P], 
        CASE WHEN M.[AwayTeamScore] > M.[HomeTeamScore] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [W], 
        CASE WHEN M.[AwayTeamScore] = M.[HomeTeamScore] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [D], 
        CASE WHEN M.[AwayTeamScore] < M.[HomeTeamScore] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [L], 
        M.[AwayTeamScore] AS [PF], 
        M.[HomeTeamScore] AS [PA], 
        (M.[AwayTeamScore] - M.[HomeTeamScore]) AS [PD], 
        M.[AwayTeamTries] AS [TF], 
        M.[HomeTeamTries] AS [TA], 
        (M.[AwayTeamTries] - M.[HomeTeamTries]) AS [TD], 
        CASE 
            WHEN M.[AwayTeamScore] > M.[HomeTeamScore] THEN 4 
            WHEN M.[AwayTeamScore] = M.[HomeTeamScore] THEN 2 
            WHEN M.[AwayTeamScore] < M.[HomeTeamScore] THEN 0 
        END AS [PTS], 
        CASE 
            WHEN ((M.[HomeTeamScore] - M.[AwayTeamScore]) BETWEEN 1 AND 7) AND M.[AwayTeamTries] >= 4 THEN 2 
            WHEN ((M.[HomeTeamScore] - M.[AwayTeamScore]) BETWEEN 1 AND 7) THEN 1 
            WHEN M.[AwayTeamTries] >= 4 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS [BP] 
    FROM 
        Match AS M 
        INNER JOIN Team AS AT 
            ON M.[AwayTeamId] = AT.[TeamId] 
    WHERE 
        M.[AwayTeamScore] IS NOT NULL 
        AND AT.[Pool] = @Pool 
    )

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY 
            SUM([BP] + [PTS]) DESC, 
            SUM([PD]) DESC, 
            SUM([TD]) DESC, 
            SUM([PF]) DESC, 
            SUM([TF]) DESC) AS [Position], 
    [TeamId], 
    [TeamName], 
    SUM([P]) AS [P], 
    SUM([W]) AS [W], 
    SUM([D]) AS [D], 
    SUM([L]) AS [L], 
    SUM([PF]) AS [PF], 
    SUM([PA]) AS [PA], 
    SUM([PD]) AS [PD], 
    SUM([TF]) AS [TF], 
    SUM([TA]) AS [TA], 
    SUM([BP]) AS [BP], 
    SUM([BP] + [PTS]) AS [PTS] 
FROM 
    PoolResults 
GROUP BY 
    [TeamId], 
    [TeamName];
```

As mentioned before, this does everything EXCEPT take into consideration ranking of two teams on the same points based on who won the game between them.  **Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this initial ranking?**

**===== UPDATE TO ORIGINAL POST =====**

**CLARIFICATION** - There can be more than 2 teams on equal points, in which case each combination of 2 teams must be evaluated to determine rankings.  The following sample on SqlFiddle illustrates a scenario with 5 teams in a pool, where 3 teams have the same number of points - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0701/3

Query #1 shows the raw match data (which teams played and the scores)

Query #2 shows the unsorted pool standings:

```
Australia (10)
England (10)
Fiji (5)
Uruguay (0)
Wales (10)
```

Query #3 shows the pool standings sorted by points:

```
Australia (10)
England (10)
Wales (10)
Fiji (5)
Uruguay (0)
```

However, the real order should be:

```
Wales (10)
England (10)
Australia (10)
Fiji (5)
Uruguay (0)
```

with Wales ranked above England, because Wales beat England, and England ranked above Australia because England beat Australia

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: What is your SQL version? Could be more than two team tie on same rank at this point?

Comment: @FelixPamittan, post updated to include link to sample schema/data/queries, and clarify what the desired results are

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, SQL version is 2014, and yes, more than 2 teams can tie on the same number of points

Comment: @bosco What about ties on that level? Say team A, B, C, D are tie rank 5. Are all combination between those assure one team win or also may exist ties?

Comment: Great jon with the new fiddle. But now Im a litle angry because you didnt include that on the first post . That would save us a lot of time.

Comment: My apologies @JuanCarlosOropeza, I wasn't even aware of the existence of SqlFiddle until you referenced it in your answer. Duly noted for future posts/questions, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Now I have to say `Im Sorry`. I just remember when I first meet sqlFiddle and was my bad assume you already know about it. Now regarding your question the current set of instructions have big problem and can't be solve because data can have contradictons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need sql 2012+ using `LEAD()` and `LAG()` [**functions**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/), Also require only two team have same Rank at this moment.

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([team] varchar(1), [rank] int);

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([team], [rank])
VALUES
    ('A', 1),('B', 1),('C', 2);

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([team1] varchar(1), [team2] varchar(1), [win] varchar(1));

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([team1], [team2], [win])
VALUES
    ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'A'),('C', 'B', 'B');
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afad1/7)**

```
WITH breakTie AS ( 
    SELECT
        [team],
        [rank],
        LAG([team]) OVER (ORDER BY [rank]) PreviousTeam,
        LEAD([team]) OVER (ORDER BY [rank]) NextTeam,
        LAG([rank]) OVER (ORDER BY [rank]) PreviousRank,
        LEAD([rank]) OVER (ORDER BY [rank]) NextRank
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT *, CASE 
       WHEN B.[rank] = B.[NextRank] and B.[team] = T.[win] THEN 1
       WHEN B.[rank] = B.[PreviousRank] and B.[team] = T.[win] THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END as breakT
FROM breakTie B
LEFT JOIN Table2 T
   ON ( B.team = T.team1 or B.team = T.team2)
  AND ( B.NextTeam = T.team1 or B.NextTeam = T.team2)
ORDER BY 
    [rank],
    CASE 
       WHEN B.[rank] = B.[NextRank] and B.[team] = T.[win] THEN 1
       WHEN B.[rank] = B.[PreviousRank] and B.[team] = T.[win] THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated, but I would try the following.

1. Make a view each combination of opponents and who wins the tie.
2. With the results of your current ranking add in a column for the prior player, a column for prior rank, a column for next rank using windowing functions
3. Join to the view in step 1
4. Make a case statement that only sets a value if prior rank or next rank is equal that has the value from the view in step 1.
5. Sort by rank and the column in step 4

Comment: Did you think how handle if more than 2 team are tie on same rank? I think that part can affect my code.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Good question -- the OP gave no requirements how that would work... so I guess random is fine.  :P

Comment: @Hogan If more than 2 are tied on same rank, each pair of teams must be evaluated to see who won in their game - see sample added to post above

Comment: @bosco -- that is not helpful -- what if there are 3 tied -- a beat b, b beat c, c beat a.  Who goes first.

Comment: Sorry @Hogan, I'm just calling out the rules as defined at http://www.rugbyworldcup.com/tournament-rules in section 1.1.3 ... My assumption is that if the teams can't be ranked conclusively by looking at the outcome of each pairing, you move onto the next criteria (PF, TF, PD, TD)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some other suggestion. Because your current problem have some contradictions and may not have a proper ***answer*** with current rules.
[image]

- First picture 4 team tie in same rank. If you use the information of the first 4 rows. You get a positions `D, A, B, C` but then last two can't be enforce.

  - In NFL they have some tie break called `inside conference win`. So you could count how many win each team have inside this group as a way of order.
  - So now all condition are pair comparasion.
  - In this case A and D have more wins and D beat A.
  - Now C beat B and A beat C. And you have a real order.
- But as show in picture 2 you can have everyone tie with 2 win.

My guess is you should analyze the restrictions. Maybe the order of rules is different and you can reduce *THIS* problem to one where only two team are tie.